# How do you merge data frames (with the same name) created through a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a for loop to iterate through a list to create a data frame using a function on each element in that list. How do I then join the data frames? They all have the same name.

I'm working with somewhat sensitive data so I can't share the code but it's something like.

```
list = [a,b.c]
for letter in list:
    df = function(letter)
```

How do I then join the dfs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add each dataframe to a list and concatenate in the end. Something like:

```
list = [a,b.c]
df_list = []
for letter in list:
    df_list.append(function(letter))
result_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like :

```
df_final = None
list = [a,b,c]
for letter in list:
    df = function(letter)
    if df_final is None:
        df_final = df
    else:
        df_final = df_final.join(df, on=..., how=...)
```

Comment: How can `df_final ` even change?

Comment: df_final is updated at each loop since you either initiate df_final (first loop), or join other dataframes (loop >1)